# Do we still need to separately define static members, even if they are initialised inside the class definition?

Tags: c++, c++11, language-lawyer

In C++03, we had the ability to initialize `const` `static` class data members inline within the class definition, [but still had to *define* the member](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7092830/560648) [if it were to be *odr-used*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9786029/560648).

Is this still the case in C++11?

```
struct Foo
{
   static const int x = 3;
};

const int Foo::x;
// ^ required?
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### Yes.

> `[C++11: 9.4.2/3]:` **If a non-volatile `const` `static` data member is of integral or enumeration type, its declaration in the class definition can specify a *brace-or-equal-initializer* in which every *initializer-clause* that is an *assignment-expression* is a constant expression** (5.19). A `static` data member of literal type can be declared in the class definition with the `constexpr` specifier; if so, its declaration shall specify a *brace-or-equal-initializer* in which every *initializer-clause* that is an *assignment-expression* is a constant expression. *[ Note:* In both these cases, the member may appear in constant expressions. *—end note ]* **The member shall still be defined in a namespace scope if it is odr-used (3.2) in the program and the namespace scope definition shall not contain an *initializer*.**

This is comparable to the wording in C++03:

> `[C++03: 9.4.2/2]:` If a static data member is of `const` integral or `const` enumeration type, its declaration in the class definition can specify a *constant-initializer* which shall be an integral constant expression (5.19). In that case, the member can appear in integral constant expressions. The member shall still be defined in a namespace scope if it is used in the program and the namespace scope definition shall not contain an *initializer*.

As you can see, the rule itself hasn't changed at all, beyond the introduction of rules for `constexpr`.

Comment: There was also a change in the definition of odr-used, which can impact which members are required to be defined.

Comment: @DaveS: Good point. Alas, the respective definitions of _odr-used_ in both (actually C++03 calls it "potentially evaluated") is too complex to be injected into this answer. :(