# In class static const ODR

Tags: c++, gcc, linker, one-definition-rule

I am a bit confused by the `static` in-class initialization of a `const` member. For example, in the code below:

```
#include <iostream>

struct Foo
{
    const static int n = 42;
};

// const int Foo::n; // No ODR

void f(const int& param)
{
    std::cout << param << std::endl;
}

int g(const int& param)
{
    return param;
}

template<int N>
void h()
{
    std::cout << N << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    // f(Foo::n); // linker error, both g++/clang++
    std::cout << g(Foo::n) << std::endl; // OK in g++ only with -O(1,2 or 3) flag, why?!
    h<Foo::n>(); // this should be fine
}
```

<kbd>[Live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1af2cb53dc649007)</kbd>

I do not define `Foo::n` (the line is commented). So, I expect the call `f(Foo::n)` to fail at link time, and indeed it does. However, the following line `std::cout << g(Foo::n) << std::endl;` compiles and links fine only by gcc (clang still emits a linker error) whenever I use an optimization flag such as `-O1/2/3`.

1. Why does gcc (tried with gcc5.2.0 and gcc 4.9.3) compile **and link** the code when the optimization is turned on?
2. And am I correct to say that **the only usage of in-class static const members is in constant expressions**, such as template parameters like in the `h<Foo::n>` call, in which case the code should link?

Comment: [odr violations do not require a diagnostic](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28446388/1708801).

Comment: Is this specifically a C++11 question? The odr quotes [change a bit between C++11 and C++14](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28846608/1708801) although I don't think it really matters in this case but in some cases it does.

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour I compiled using `-std=c++11`, but the question per se is not necessarily C++11 (or C++14) only. O observed the same behaviour with `-std=c++98` also.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ODR violations do not require a diagnostic, from the draft C++ standard standard section `3.2` [basic.def.odr] (*emphasis mine going forward*):

> Every program shall contain exactly one definition of every non-inline
>   function or variable that is odr-used in that program; **no diagnostic
>   required**.

So inconsistent behavior at different optimization levels is perfectly conformant behavior.

Informally a variable is [odr-used](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/definition#ODR-use) if:

> its address is taken, or a reference is bound to it, and a function is odr-used if a function call to it is made or its address is taken. If an object or a function is odr-used, its definition must exist somewhere in the program; a violation of that is a link-time error.

So both `f` and `g` will be odr-uses and require a definition.

The relevant C++14 quote on odr-use would be from section *[basic.def.odr]*:

> A variable x whose name appears as a potentially-evaluated expression ex is **odr-used by ex unless** applying
>   the lvalue-to-rvalue conversion (4.1) to x yields a constant expression (5.19) that does not invoke any nontrivial
>   functions and, **if x is an object, ex is an element of the set of potential results of an expression e,
>   where either the lvalue-to-rvalue conversion (4.1) is applied to e, or e is a discarded-value expression** [...]

The wording in C++11 is similar, the changes from C++11 to C++14 are reflected in [defect report 712](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#712).

Before C++11 it is [a bit more complicated but in principle the same for this case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31565836/does-potentially-evaluated-means-the-same-as-odr-used-in-c03).

Answer (score 6):

I suppose that the compiler performs the following actions during the optimization:

- The value `const static int n` is inlined everywhere. No memory is allocated for the variable `n`, references to it becomes invalid. The function `f()` need a reference to `n` so the program is not compiled.
- The function `g` is short and simple. It is effectively inlined and optimized. After the optimization, the function `g` does not need a reference to `n`, it just returns constant value 42.

The solution is to define the variable outside the class:

```
struct Foo
{
    const static int n;
};

const int Foo::n = 42;
```

Comment: Alternative solutions are to make it  `constexpr` or an enum value. A `constexpr` is arguable better, now that compilers support it in general, because it's less source code and because it works nicely in headers.

Answer (score 4):

Formally, ODR violations are *undefined behaviour*, so the compiler may exhibit any behaviour it likes. That's why the behaviour changes with optimization level and compiler- the compiler has no obligation to maintain a particular behaviour.

Answer (score 2):

There is no definition at all. GCC 4.9.2 doesn't compile and link that with any flags.

Note, that:

```
const static int n = 42;
```

is a *declaration* and *initializer*, but not a *definition*.

Comment: I am aware that that's no definition, however as you can see from the live example, the code is compiled and linked.

Comment: That's strange. I don't have gcc4.9.2, but have 4.9.3 from macports on OS X, and it compiles and links.

Comment: it might be optimizer issue, but there is still no definition.

Comment: Look here: http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/o9HLkpgJAyibg36t That's 4.9.2, and it links. And yes, I know that's no definition, that's why I asked *why does gcc compile **and link** the code*?

Comment: This answer misses the point. There are some situations where the toolchain doesn't care about the missing definition, either because ODR is not invoked or because an optimisation has rendered it moot. The OP has hit one of these cases and would like to know specifically what it is (though personally, I wouldn't bother trying to rationalise about it).

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I asked mainly because I am not sure what's the use case for such an inline const static initialization. Do you know any other case except template parameter use? And I keep wondering *why* isn't such a declaration treated as a definition? Because of optimization issues?

Comment: @vsoftco: And I quote, _"though personally, I wouldn't bother trying to rationalise about it"_.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Boring Sunday for me I guess ;)

Comment: @vsoftco: The use case is to put the declaration & initializer in a header file, and the definition in a .cpp file. This way all translation units that `#include` the header will see and benefit from the initializer (for optimization), while there will still be only one definition, preventing any linking issues. It's very pragmatic.

Comment: @ArneVogel Thanks, that's true. What I wanted to say is what's the use case without a definition in the cpp file, if any.