# How to prevent optimizing away static const

Tags: c++, g++

Is it possible to prevent static const members optimization using compiler command-line options?

Here is an example:

```
template <unsigned v1>
struct TRAITS {
    static const unsigned val1 = v1;
};

template < class TRAITS >
struct foo {
    static const unsigned x1 = TRAITS::val1;
};

int main () {
    foo<TRAITS<1>> f1;
    // SET BREAKPOINT HERE
    return 0;
}
```

Compile:

```
g++ -g -O0 optimize_out.cpp
```

GDB:

```
gdb a.out
(gdb) break optimize_out.cpp:13
(gdb) r
(gdb) p f1 
$1 = {static x1 = <optimized out>}
```

What is specific about this code is that classes are templates. Probably there is something in C++ standard that forces compiler to optimize fields away, even with -O0 ?
When I don't use templates, values are not optimized away:

```
struct foo {
    static const unsigned x1 = 1;
};
```

In this case I can see x1 in debugger

Comment: Have you tried `print foo<TRAITS<1>>::x1`?

Comment: @immibis (gdb) print foo<TRAITS<1> >::x1
$1 = <optimized out>

Comment: My guess is if you odr-use the variable it can't be optimized away [see this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32812663/1708801)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `used` attribute to tell the compiler to emit the definition even if it isn't needed by anything:

```
template <unsigned v1>
struct TRAITS {
    static const unsigned val1 [[gnu::used]] = v1;
};

template < class TRAITS >
struct foo {
    static const unsigned x1 [[gnu::used]] = TRAITS::val1;
};
```

Alternatively, you could add out-of-line definitions of the static variables (which would be needed anyway if you odr-used them) and add the attribute to those definitions:

```
template < class TRAITS >
  const unsigned foo<TRAITS>::x1 [[gnu::used]];

template <unsigned v1>
  const unsigned TRAITS<v1>::val1 [[gnu::used]];
```